# Setting up ssh in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to setup git ssh client on my windows PC. I was logged in to the PC as a domain user and I installed git and set up the ssh client through the domain user account which I was logged in. My issue is when I generate the ssh key it creates in my private shared folder in the server instead of the default location locally.

Is there anyway I can set the default ssh key generation location in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to map the domain user home directory locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but this is an SSH configuration rather than a git one. Your personal configuration file is (on Windows it would be in your `private shared folder\.ssh`):

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Edit this file (and create it if it does not exist already) and set the following:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile /<drive letter>/<a path>/.ssh/<your_priv_key_name>
```

This two lines tell that for all hosts the identity file to use for SSH is in the location you specify. Of course, instead of `*` you can provide an IP address or hostname and set one identity file per host.